# losing other parameters in the url when using GET method

Tags: php

Here is my form

```
<form method="GET" action="/admin.php?rubrique=users&action=detail">
 <select name="id" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="user1">user1</option>
  <option value="user2">user2</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

When I change the select, I go to `/admin.php?id=user1` and the `rubrique` & `action` parameters are removed !

How can I preserve these values (I need to user `GET` method).

Is the only solution is using some hidden inputs ?

Comment: There's a typo in your code: the opening `select` tag is missing a `>`.

Comment: (ok just corrected that):  but this is not the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The browser does indeed not *append* values to the existing query parameters in `action`, it *overwrites* it completely. Simply use hidden form elements to transport those static query values:

```
<input type="hidden" name="rubrique" value="users">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="detail">
```

They will be send together with the selected value as query parameters.

Comment: ok that is what I supposed. Is there a tool/config so I can keep them or automatically rewrite them into hidden fields ?

Comment: `foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) printf('<input type="hidden" ..>', ..);` ?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hidden input fields for `rubrique` and `action`

```
<input type="hidden" name="rubrique" value="users" />

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="detail" />
```

Comment: Just to note: if you literally hardcode `'users'`, there's no need to run it through `htmlspecialchars`. That's only necessary if you have *variable values*. But then indeed you need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of `ID` and assign it to `window.location` to reload page via following method.

Try

```
<form method="GET" action="/admin.php?rubrique=users&action=detail">
    <select name="id" onchange="window.location='/admin.php?rubrique=users&amp;action=detail&amp;id='+this.value">
        <option value="user1">user1</option>
        <option value="user2">user2</option>
    </select>
</form>
```